# Why does my compiler think my readlink() is implicitly declared if I set the standard to c99 or c11?

Tags: c, c99, implicit-declaration

I have toy code that looks like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                         
#include <unistd.h>                                                                         
                                                                                         
int main()                                                                                  
{                                                                                           
    readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/my/path", 128);                                            
                                                                                         
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

When I compile with

```
icc main.c -o helloworld
```

everything is fine but when I e.g. try

```
icc -std=c99 main.c -o helloworld
```

or

```
icc -std=c11 main.c -o helloworld
```

I get the error message

```
main.c(6): warning #266: function "readlink" declared implicitly
```

What is it about c11 (or c99) standards that induces this error?

Comment: `readlink` is not a C standard function. It is Posix. So not surprising that there are warnings if the compiler is told to conform to a C standard.

Comment: Ok. Though one additional point of interest: If I set -std=c90 there is no warning

Comment: Haven't looked deeply into the details of the different standards so I could be off here. But my recollection is that c90 has a default/automatic declaration for implicit functions whereas from c99 there is no such default implicit declaration.

Comment: Yes, implicit declarations were removed in c99, and are not a part of c11 either.

Comment: That's still weird though because unistd.h isn't a standard header, so why would it be affected by -std=cxx? If this was another case of POSIX trash dumped in standard headers, that would be another story.

Comment: Changing the version of the C standard or specification to use does not make the compiler think the function is implicitly declared. With any of the C standard versions 1990, 1999, or 2011, the function was not explicitly declared. In all cases, when the compiler encountered the call to the function, it treated that as an implicit declaration. In the 1990 version, this was allowed (per clause 6.3.2.2), and the compiler did not issue a warning. In the 1999 and 2011 versions, this provision was dropped, so it is improper code, so the compiler issues a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is wrapped in

```
#if defined __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED || defined __USE_XOPEN2K
```

From the man page for `readlink` you need to set the proper source definition first.
The current POSIX definition can be set with `gcc -std=c11 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L`
If you don't set everything correctly you get to hunt undefined behavior because `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void*)` aren't the same anymore. Implicit declarations really did need to go for 64 bit to become.

`-std=gnu11` flips everything on. If you don't have to care if you accidentally use a gcc extension or not, just set it in your makefile and forget about it.